# How can I tell what edition of SQL Server runs on the machine?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running SQL Server 2005 but I am unsure which edition this is. How can I decide what edition (Express, Standard, Enterprise etc) is running on the machine?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
select @@version
```

> #### Sample Output
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)   Mar 29 2009 10:11:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7600: )

If you just want to get the edition, you can use:

```
select serverproperty('Edition')
```

To use in an automated script, you can get the edition ID, which is an integer:

```
select serverproperty('EditionID')
```

- -1253826760 = Desktop
- -1592396055 = Express
- -1534726760 = Standard
- 1333529388 = Workgroup
- 1804890536 = Enterprise
- -323382091 = Personal
- -2117995310 = Developer
- 610778273 = Enterprise Evaluation
- 1044790755 = Windows Embedded SQL
- 4161255391 = Express with Advanced Services

Comment: please, note that this field is actually bigint
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx

Comment: Great information!  This was hard to find, thank you so much.  Still seems relevant years later.

Answer (score 22):

I use this query here to get all relevant info (relevant for me, at least :-)) from SQL Server:

```
SELECT  
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as 'Product Version', 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel') as 'Product Level',  
    SERVERPROPERTY('edition') as 'Product Edition',
    SERVERPROPERTY('buildclrversion') as 'CLR Version',
    SERVERPROPERTY('collation') as 'Default Collation',
    SERVERPROPERTY('instancename') as 'Instance',
    SERVERPROPERTY('lcid') as 'LCID',
    SERVERPROPERTY('servername') as 'Server Name'
```

That gives you an output something like this:

```
Product Version   Product Level   Product Edition             CLR Version   
10.0.2531.0       SP1             Developer Edition (64-bit)    v2.0.50727  

Default Collation     Instance   LCID   Server Name 
Latin1_General_CI_AS     NULL    1033   *********
```

Answer (score 15):

You can get just the edition name by using the following steps.

- Open "SQL Server Configuration Manager"
- From the List of SQL Server Services, Right Click on "SQL Server (Instance_name)" and Select Properties.
- Select "Advanced" Tab from the Properties window.
- Verify Edition Name from the "Stock Keeping Unit Name"
- Verify Edition Id from the "Stock Keeping Unit Id"
- Verify Service Pack from the "Service Pack Level"
- Verify Version from the "Version"

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Xob.png)

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't have a login to the SQL DB itself (just the server) and needed to know the edition.

Answer (score 7):

You can get just the edition (plus under individual properties) using [SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396(SQL.90).aspx)

e.g.

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
```

Quote (for "Edition"):

> Installed product edition of the
>   instance of SQL Server. Use the value
>   of this property to determine the
>   features and the limits, such as
>   maximum number of CPUs, that are
>   supported by the installed product.
>   Returns: 
> 'Desktop Engine' (Not
>   available for SQL Server 2005.)
>   'Developer Edition'
>  'Enterprise
>   Edition'
>  'Enterprise Evaluation
>   Edition'
>  'Personal Edition'(Not
>   available for SQL Server 2005.)
>   'Standard Edition'
>  'Express Edition'
>   'Express Edition with Advanced
>   Services'
>  'Workgroup Edition'
>  'Windows
>   Embedded SQL'
>  Base data type:
>   nvarchar(128)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') = -1253826760 THEN 'Desktop'
         WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') = -1592396055 THEN 'Express'
         WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') = -1534726760 THEN 'Standard'
         WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') = 1333529388 THEN 'Workgroup'
         WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') = 1804890536 THEN 'Enterprise'
         WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') = -323382091 THEN 'Personal'
         WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') = -2117995310  THEN 'Developer'
         WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') = 610778273  THEN 'Windows Embedded SQL'
         WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') = 4161255391   THEN 'Express with Advanced Services'
    END AS 'Edition';
```