# How to check whether the installed instance is full SQL Server or just SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server

In one of my project, first I need to check whether SQL Server is installed on the machine or not. I am doing this with the code shown here:

```c#
 var sqlRegistry = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server", true);

 if (sqlRegistry == null) 
 { }
 else 
 { }
```

But in the `else` part, I need to know whether the installed SQL Server is "only" SQL Server Express, or a full SQL Server edition.

How will I go for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell what edition of SQL Server runs on the machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070396/how-can-i-tell-what-edition-of-sql-server-runs-on-the-machine)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine installed SQL Server instances and their versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the installed instances in the registry key:

```
Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\InstalledInstances
```

This will contain all the installed instances, e.g. on my system:

```
MSSQLSERVER
SQLEXPRESS
```

Go into this registry key with this value:

```
Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL
```

to get the actual instance name that you need in the next step.

Now if you go look at the registry key:

```
Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\(InstanceName)\Setup\Edition
```

there you have a value of e.g. `Express` for a SQL Server Express, or `Developer Edition` or something else. That should tell you if you have `Express` or another, "full" edition of SQL Server

Comment: Thanks for so deep answer.

Answer (score 3):

SQL-Server seems to have a built-in function [`SERVERPROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx), so you should be able to query the server via SQL, like:

`SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')`

Comment: and what if MS SQL server stopped?

Comment: that was sarcasm? =) I really have this kind of question what if it's stopped right now but still installed.

Comment: Maybe there's something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions

Answer (score 3):

Here some code that get installed **MS SQL Server Editions** on server to console based on @marc_s answer:

```
//This line open Registry with x64 View from x86 process. Usually SQL server installed in x64 edition, otherwise you should check x86
var localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
var msSQLServer = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
var instances = (string[])msSQLServer.GetValue("InstalledInstances");

foreach (var instance in instances)
{
    var insNames = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL");
    var realNameInstanse = (string)insNames.GetValue(instance);
    var sqlEditionRegistry = localMachine.OpenSubKey(string.Format(@"Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\{0}\Setup", realNameInstanse));
    var edition = (string)sqlEditionRegistry.GetValue("Edition");
    Console.WriteLine("Instance {0}, RealName {2}, - Edition: {1}", instance, edition, realNameInstanse);
}
```

Here is edition list based on list at the end of this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321185/):

- Standard Edition
- 64-bit Edition
- Express Edition
- Developer Edition
- Enterprise Edition
- Workgroup Edition
- Standard
- Analysis Services
- Developer
- Enterprise
- Enterprise Evaluation
- Express
- Express with Advanced Services
- Integration Services
- Datacenter
- Reporting Services
- Standard Edition for Small Business
- Web
- Workgroup
- Business Intelligence
- Enterprise Core

Answer (score 0):

To check sql server version, you can query for `@@version`.

```
execute select @@version
```

The output consists of:

1. SQL server version
2. SQL server edition
3. Latest patch installed
4. Computer's processor (32 bit or 64 bit)