# How is the memory used greater than the SQL Server Express limitation?

Tags: sql-server, limit, sql-server-2014-express

[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx) tells me that SQL Server 2014 Express should have **Maximum memory utilized (per instance of SQL Server Database Engine)** of 1 GB.

Whenever I run this simple script to tell me the **Physical Memory In Use** I get 4 GB.

```
SELECT dopm.physical_memory_in_use_kb 
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory AS dopm;
```

[image]

Here's the version info.

[image]

What gives?  The server itself has 24 GB of RAM so I'd like SQL Server to use more if possible.  I think I'd have start using a different edition of SQL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this link

[SQL Server 2014 Editions](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/waterox-sql/2014/04/22/2014-sql-server-editions-overview/)

> Express Edition
>
> Express edition is a free version of SQL Server that is limited in its
>   functionality and size. Is limited to one socket with a maximum of
>   four cores for CPU power, 1 GB of memory, and a database size. No
>   larger than 10 GB. **If using the reporting features, The maximum memory
>   is raised to 4 GB.** Express edition is compatible with all other
>   editions of SQL Server. Express edition has a few different versions
>   that can be downloaded

And according to [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), you will find that **4GB RAM limit** is at `Maximum memory utilized (per instance of Reporting Services)` for **Express with Advanced Services**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070396/how-can-i-tell-what-edition-of-sql-server-runs-on-the-machine I saw that during my research too.  I'm not convinced that's the answer.  The link in this comment says 'Express Edition with Advanced Services' is the edition I would receive when running the select serverproperty('Edition') query, but I get 'Express Edition'

Comment: Try select `EditionID`, is it -1592396055 or -133711905?

Comment: It's Express Edition, however, you can read more here http://knowledge.3essentials.com/web-hosting/article/433/Evaluating-SQL-Server-2005-Express-vs-other-SQL-2005-versions.html

Comment: In the link: `The 1 GB RAM limit is the memory limit available for the buffer pool. The buffer pool is used to store data pages and other information. However, memory needed to keep track of connections, locks, etc. is not counted toward the buffer pool limit. It is therefore possible that the server will use more than 1 GB in total, but it will never use more than 1GB for the buffer pool. This limitation prevents the use of Address Windowing Extensions (AWE) with SQL Server Express.`

Comment: Most of the examples I saw had the memory a little about 1 GB (the little extra I thought would account to store the data pages and other information), but 4 GB is what I'm seeing.  That's a lot of space just for data pages and other information.  That's 3 times the amount of space used for the buffer pool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89464/discussion-between-mark-and-bnk).