# How Many RAM is available in MS SQL Server Express Edition using the In-Memory OLTP technique

Tags: sql-server, oltp, in-memory-tables

Starting with the 2016 version the In-Memory-technique is also integrated in the MS SQL Server Express edition. In fact as the Express version is limited to 1 GB RAM I'm wondering whether the RAM for the In-Memory OLTP technique is used as part of the 1 GB RAM or whether it will not affect the 1 GB RAM.

Comment: Check out this answer: [How is the memory used greater than the SQL Server Express limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535476/how-is-the-memory-used-greater-than-the-sql-server-express-limitation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer pool and memory for In-Memory OLTP objects are separate limits, documented here:

[Editions and supported features of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016)

Comment: Am I'm reading it right, that In-Memory OLTP could use 352 MB on the SQL Server Express edition?