# Programmatically determine if Change Data Capture feature can be turned on

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, change-data-capture

**Background**

We have a tool that can run against any version of sql server.

We want to add the ability for that tool to turn on CDC and configure capturing of some tables, without the user writing any SQL.

I know I can query if CDC is enabled from sys.databases. But that's after the fact.

**Question**

Is there any way to determine if the CDC feature **can** be enabled on this database?
I expected some kind of sys.server_capabilities table, or sys.server_features table. It may be possible via interpreting SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition'), but that feels like a facepalm.

Comment: This may help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070396/how-can-i-tell-what-edition-of-sql-server-runs-on-the-machine

Comment: another good article on CDC https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/performance-tuning-sql-server-change-tracking/

Comment: @GuidoG Interesting article thanks! But Change Tracking is not CDC - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519(v=sql.105).aspx